# How to fetch data from joining two tables with condition on both tables using Hibernate with ManyToOne mapping?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have follwing two tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subs")
public class Subs {

    @Column(name = "cin_id")
    private Long cinId;
    @ManyToOne(
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}
    )
    @JoinColumn(
      name = "cinId",
      insertable = false,
      updatable = false
    )

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(
      name = "status"
    )
    private String status;


    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(
      name = "mode"
    )
    private String mode;

}
```

Second table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cin")
public class Cin {
    
        @Id
        @Column(
          name = "cinId"
        )

        private Long id;
        @OneToMany(
          fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
          mappedBy = "cinId"
        )
        private List<Subs> subs;

        @Column(
          name = "is_eligible"
        )
        private Boolean isEligible;

        @Column(
          name = "is_fix"
        )
        private Boolean is_fix;
        
    
}
```

I want to write a DAO service in hibernate to fetch rows from CIN table where the result should be fetched based on where clause for status and mode value in subs table and is_eligible and is_fix value in Cin table.

Basically Hibernate equivalent to below query:

```
select 
    cin.id, 
from subs
inner join cin
ON subs.cinId=cin.cinId
where (subs.mode = 'something' and subs.status ='something')
and  cin.isEligible = true and cin.isFix = false
```

I am aware of doing it using Query.setParameters thing but not sure how to do this if we want to apply condition on both the joining tables with Many to one relationship.

Comment: Your `@OneToMany` is missing a field definition

Answer (score 0):

```
from Cin c
where (c.subs.mode = :param1 and c.subs.status = :param2)
and  c.isEligible = true and c.isFix = false
```

should work for you